# What is spark.local.ip ,spark.driver.host,spark.driver.bindAddress and spark.driver.hostname?

Tags: apache-spark

What will be difference and use of all these?

- spark.local.ip
- spark.driver.host
- spark.driver.bindAddress
- spark.driver.hostname

How to fix a machine as a Driver in Spark standalone cluster ?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html .... Did you read that?

Comment: Yes, but not clear how to fix a machine as a Driver in Spark standalone cluster on every spark submit?

Comment: What isn't clear about *"Hostname or IP address for the driver*"?

Comment: I fixed all these (spark.local.ip , spark.driver.host and spark.driver.bindAddress ) to a single IP  and start my cluster and submit a application then driver IP is differed from which one i set.

Comment: I experienced the same behavior. Setting the spark.driver.host does not fix the driver to a specific worker.

Comment: Yeah, 5 years later this is till laughably undocumented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Short Version

the ApplicationMaster connect to spark Driver by spark.driver.host

spark Driver bind to bindAddress on the client machine

## by examples

### 1 example of port binding

```
.config('spark.driver.port','50243')
```

then `netstat -ano` on windows

```
TCP    172.18.1.194:50243     0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15332
TCP    172.18.1.194:50243     172.18.7.122:54451     ESTABLISHED     15332
TCP    172.18.1.194:50243     172.18.7.124:37412     ESTABLISHED     15332
TCP    172.18.1.194:50243     172.18.7.142:41887     ESTABLISHED     15332
TCP    [::]:4040              [::]:0                 LISTENING       15332
```

The nodes in the cluster `172.18.7.1xx` are in the same network as my development machine `172.181.1.194` as my netmask is `255.255.248.0`

### 2 example of specify ip from ApplicationMaster to Driver

```
.config('spark.driver.host','192.168.132.1')
```

then `netstat -ano`

```
TCP    192.168.132.1:58555    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9480
TCP    192.168.132.1:58641    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9480
TCP    [::]:4040              [::]:0                 LISTENING       9480
```

however the ApplicationMaster cannot connect and reported error

```
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

because this ip is a VM bridge on my development machine

### 3 example of ip bind

```
.config('spark.driver.host','172.18.1.194')
.config('spark.driver.bindAddress','192.168.132.1')
```

then `netstat -ano`

```
TCP    172.18.1.194:63937     172.18.7.101:8032      ESTABLISHED     17412
TCP    172.18.1.194:63940     172.18.7.102:9000      ESTABLISHED     17412
TCP    172.18.1.194:63952     172.18.7.121:50010     ESTABLISHED     17412
TCP    192.168.132.1:63923    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       17412
TCP    [::]:4040              [::]:0                 LISTENING       17412
```

## Detailed Version

Before explain in detail, there are only these three related conf variables:

- `spark.driver.host`
- `spark.driver.port`
- `spark.driver.bindAddress`

There are **NO** variables like `spark.driver.hostname` or `spark.local.ip`. But there **IS** a environment variable called `SPARK_LOCAL_IP`

and before explain the variables, first we have to understand the application submition process

Main Roles of computers:

- development machine
- master node (YARN / Spark Master)
- worker node

There is an ApplicationMaster for each application, which takes care of resource request from cluster and status monitor of jobs(stages)

The ApplicationMaster is in the cluster, always.

Place of spark Driver

- development machine: client mode
- within the cluster: cluster mode, same place as the ApplicationMaster

Let's say we are talking about client mode

The spark application can be submitted from a development machine, which act as a client machine of the application, as well as a client machine of the cluster.

The spark application can alternatively submitted from a node within the cluster (master node or worker node or just a specific machine with no resource manager role)

The client machine might not be placed within the same subnet as the cluster and this is one case that these variables try to deal with. Think about your internet connection, it is often not possible that your laptop can be accessed from anywhere around the globe just as google.com.

At the beginning of the application submission process, the spark-submit on the client side would upload necessary files to the spark master or yarn, and negotiate about resource requests. In this step the client connect to the cluster, and the cluster address is the destination address that the client tries to connect.

Then the ApplicationMaster starts on the allocated resource.

The resource allocated for ApplicationMaster is by default random, and cannot control by these variables. It is controlled by the scheduler of the cluster, if you're curious about this.

Then the ApplicationMaster tries to connect **BACK** to the spark Driver. This is the place that these conf variables take effects.

Comment: Why doesn't the cluster (master) tell AppliationMaster where the driver is? The cluster knows the driver's ip when the driver connects to it.

Comment: @colinfang your local system cannot be accessed from outside.
You need to submit the tasks from a system that is accesible back from the master

Comment: @colinfang by default it(master) knows the client ip. However this answer solves the question where the client ip is mapped by routing OR port is not accessible, and needs port/ip forwarding. Ja8zyjits explains this scenario, where an edge node is used to connect from master to client.